# Smallest non-affine scheme. Is this correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X:=\{p,q_1, q_2\}$ be a topological space with topology $\mathcal{T}:=\{\emptyset, \{p\}, \{q_1,p\}, \{q _2, p\}, X\}$. Define a sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ by 
$$\mathcal{O}(\emptyset) := \{0\}, \quad  \mathcal{O}(\{p\}) := k(x), \quad  \mathcal{O}(\{p, q_1\})= \mathcal{O}(\{p, q_2\}) = \mathcal{O}(X) := (k[x])_{(x)}$$
with the evident restritions morphisms. Then is it true that?

$$\mathcal{O}_p \cong k(x), \quad \mathcal{O}_{q_1} \cong \mathcal{O}_{q_2} \cong  (k[x])_{(x)} $$

Attempt: Yes, it is true, for example every element of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_p$ has a unique representant of the form $(\{p\}, f)$ with $f \in k(X)$ and we see that the multiplication of such classes is exactly the same multiplication of the field $k(x)$. More formally,

$$ k(x) \to \mathcal{O}_p: f \mapsto [(f,\{p\})] $$ is an isomorphism of rings.

Is this correct?

Comment: I am a little confused. In your notation, what is the difference between $k(x)$ and $(k[x])_{(x)}$?

Comment: $k(x)$ is the fraction field of $k[x]$. $(k[x])_{(x)}$ is the localisation of $k[x]$ at the prime ideal $(x)$. So the latter is strictly contained in the former.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think your attempt is correct BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the help!